# Leaflet overlay control will not hide ImageOverlay when it is disabled

Tags: leaflet, layers

I use leaflet 1.3.2 and i have a function that successfully creates a hash map of *Overlay Layers* from a Json file.

### JSON

```
 "overlay": [{            
            "name": "Manfredonia",
            "enable": true,
            "collapsed": false,
            "path": "vid/nasa.mp4",
            "ne_lat": 13,
            "ne_lon": -100,
            "sw_lat": 32,
            "sw_lon": -130
        }]
```

### JS

```
var overlaylayers = {};
// This function reads values from the aforementioned JSON file
// It iterates a list of values and saves them in a *overlaylayers*
function construct_Overlay(k, overlay) {
  let bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(
    new L.LatLng(overlay.sw_lat, overlay.sw_lon),
    new L.LatLng(overlay.ne_lat, overlay.ne_lon)
  );
  let path = subfeatures.path;
  let content = L.imageOverlay(path, bounds);
  // Setting key-value in *overlayLayers* 
  overlayLayers[overlay.name] = content;
  // Adding it in the list of the layers that are going to appear
  map.addLayer(overlayLayers[overlay.name]);
}
```

I call the above function that instantiates the *overlaylayers* .

```
 construct_Overlay(k, v);
```

Then i use *Overlay Layers* in order to create an *Overlay control* on my existing *map*,

```
var overlayControl = L.control.layers(null, overlayLayers, {position:'bottomright'}).addTo(map);
```

The layer is enabled (and therefore visible on the map) by default.
The problem is that if i disable the layer from the `overlayControl`, then the overlaid image will remain visible.
[image]

Comment: Can you share construct_Overlay method?

Comment: @senolozgur I added the function

Comment: You are adding items to a `overlayLayers` hashmap, then you're overwriting that variable with the return value of the function call (which evaluates to `undefined`), but still you pass that to the control constructor. I'm gonna guess that you don't have full awareness of what the value of `overlayLayers` is, and you're somehow creating duplicate instances of layers which you add to the map (how many times do you call `.addTo(map)`?).

Comment: @IvanSanchez Yes sorry. I was trying to simplify the code. Anyway i corrected it now. The function does not return a value but it sets it in _overlayers_ .

Comment: Can you please add the initial value of `overlayLayers`, and one feature (one sample value for `v`)?

Comment: @IvanSanchez I updated the question